# How session.credentials() is useful for setting a connection in AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda to insert data into Amazon Elasticsearch Service.

To establish a connection with the Elasticsearch instance I am using `boto3.session.get_credentials()`. I wanted to understand how that can works as security measurement? Should not Elasticsearch instance have password or fixed access_key or something?

```py
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
es = Elasticsearch(
    host=host,
    port=portOfElasticsearch,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
    http_auth=awsauth
)
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS Elasticsearch solution has some customization that allow authentication via IAM.
This means you will validate your connection using some IAM policy that allow you to connect on Elasticsearch.
That is why you have this: `http_auth=awsauth`

This code: `boto3.session.get_credentials()` get the current credential associated with your Lambda.
You didn't mention, but probably you have some role associated with your Lamda. This role has permission to connect on Elasticsearch.

Comment: @Azizie No I dont have any role associated with lambda.

Comment: There is always a role associated with lambda functions. It may have no permissions, but it is required to create one.